# Conditional link

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I have a document which only part with links and the only part I can edit is the link formula (which is more-less HTML). The links are being generated using ID. What I want is to vary the ddestination basing on the ID value.

So I have:

`<a href="http://www.worldbridge.org/Repository/peopleforscrap/person.asp?qryid=:LINK:" target="_blank">`

*:LINK: is an intige*

which gaves me in fact bunchd of links based on the passed ID (:LINK:) eg.:

`<a href="http://www.worldbridge.org/Repository/peopleforscrap/person.asp?qryid=3756" target="_blank">`

I want to differ the destination based on the ID given so that for ID < 900000 the link will be as above, but for ID > 900000 the user will be redirected to a different site using slightly modified ID. Eg. for ID = 3756 I want to get:

`<a href="http://www.worldbridge.org/Repository/peopleforscrap/person.asp?qryid=3756" target="_blank">`

but for ID = 905341 I want to get:

`<a href="http://www.msc.com.pl/cezar/?p=21&pid=5341" target="_blank">`

My main problem is that the "if statement" has to be processed by the prowsing user on a HTML site (i can insert javscript).

Comment: The question is a little hard to understand. Are you basically saying that you have a page with links like `<a href="http://example.com/?id=123">` and want JS that changes every link with an id > 900 000 to instead be `<a href="http://another.example.com/?pid=900001">`?

Comment: I want a single piece of code which looks like link and redirects users to example.com or another.example.com basing on the id which was already ahrdcoed into it. 
(yeah, it seems like it doesnt have any sense but believe me this is the only way :D )

Comment: I think a server-side solution might be better-say a redirect in .htaccess.

Comment: @isherwood I'm not that good with apache - how would you imagine proper .htaccess for this?